# Create a file on Onedrive if it does not exist with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to create an Azure Logic App that is triggered by a HTTP request, checks if a file exists on OneDrive and if the file exists, append the body of the HTTP request. If the file does not exist, the logic app should create it and add the body of the request to it as well.

How can I check if a file exists on onedrive in a Logic App / Azure function? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The OneDrive Connector has a **Find files in folder** option which you can use to test the existence of the file.

If you specify the whole file name, the response array will be empty indicating the file does not exist.

[OneDrive Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveconnector/)

Unfortunately, OneDrive does not have a native Append option.  So, you will have to handle the append in the Logic App or a Function.

Comment: How can I append content to the file in case it already exists? I'm trying to create a csv file where I want to append content line by line. I tried the OneDrive Connector Update File Action but was unable to use it to append to the file content, instead of overwriting it

Comment: @buddybubble The Append is something you will have to program yourself.

Comment: You could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/242).